# How to redirect to dashboard based on user roles in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have two components 1 is adminRoutes which displays admindashboard and the other is Userdashboard which shows userDashboard, below are screenshots of admin and user dashboards

[user dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak5X0.png), [admin dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euAuv.png)

What I did here is after successfull login i navigate to (`"/"`) which returns `<Home/>` component that is my admin dashboard.
Below is the code of login. When login button is clicked, the `useEffect` is fired.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, UserLogin.email, UserLogin.password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 
                const user = userCredential.user
                const docRef = doc(db, 'admin', user.uid)
                getDoc((docRef)).then((doc) => {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentuser', JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
                });
                dispatch({
                    type: "LOGIN",
                    payload: user
                })
                navigate("/user/");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setError(error);
                setInterval(() => {
                    setError();
                }, 4000)
            });
    }
}, [formErrors])
```

Here I am saving my currentUser from firebase to `localStorage`, user object has properties `email`, `id`, `name`, `role` and based on the `role` I want to switch admindashboard or userdashboard while I am logging in.

Here is the main `App` component code

```
function App (){
    return (
        <>
            <UserRoutes/>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

And below is `AdminRoutes` component that has different routes for admindashboard pages

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import UserDashboard from "../../UserDashBoard/UserDashboard";

export default function AdminRoutes() {
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
        return currentUser ? children : <Navigate to={"/Login"} />;
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Route path="Login" element={<Login />} />
                        <Route path="Signup" element={<Signup />} />
                        <Route
                            index
                            element={
                                <RequireAuth>
                                    <Home />
                                </RequireAuth>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route path="user">
                            <Route
                                index
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <UserList />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                            <Route
                                path=":userid"
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <User />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="documents">
                            <Route
                                index
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <Document />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="createcategory">
                            <Route
                                index
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <CreateCategory />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="viewuser">
                            <Route
                                index
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <UserList />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="uploaddoc">
                            <Route
                                index
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <Upload />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="createuser">
                            <Route
                                index
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <CreateUser />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="Viewdocuments">
                            <Route
                                index
                                element={
                                    <RequireAuth>
                                        <Document />
                                    </RequireAuth>
                                }
                            />
                        </Route>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}
```

Based on Roles I want to show Dashboard. If admin logged in show admin dashboard, if user logged in show userdashboard. How can I achieve it? I am still learning reactjs. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Edit after clarifying what OP wants to achieve:
You need to add context and then make routing based on data in it.

```
// in the App.js, wrap your components with Context so it is accessible
function App (){
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider>
            <UserRoutes/>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default App;
```

In component `UserRoutes`:

```
const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
    return currentUser ? children : <Navigate to={"/Login"} />;
};

if (currentUser.role === "admin") return ( { /* user is admin, return routes for admin */ }
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            { /* all the routes for user admin, ex. */ }
            <Route path="admindashboard" element={<AdminDashboard />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
)

return ( { /* user is regular user, return routes for user */ }
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            { /* all the routes for user, ex. */ }
            <Route path="user-dashboard" element={<UserDashboard />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
)
```

Comment: Actually there is no Routes component, it is AdminRoutes i.e my admindashboard  and i if am not wrong calling same component inside it

Comment: You have `Routes` component used inside of your `AdminRoutes` component. There is also `UserDashboard` imported in the same file, so I assumed that you want to display this component inside of `AdminRoutes`.

Comment: no  its my bad , Actually i  have two components adminRoutes and UserRoutes which are both dashboard for different user .now i want to render these component based on logged in user when someone logged in and the function return currentuserobj and there is role property which can be 'admin' or 'user' if admin then render AdminRoutes component & if role is User render UserROutes component.

Comment: I have edited my answer, take a loook :)

Comment: the useEffect cannot be called inside app js it is the part of loginComponent ,however i tried the code below the useEffect inside the appjs its not working

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: thankyou for your time .but it still not fixed cause still a lot of thing going on the the other component